# Дистанция определённой активности

Tags: java, android, google-fit

Хочу получить динстанцию например прогулки, или велосипеда или машины с помощь Google Fit. 
Не знаю как, могу получить только дистанцию например 100м, а как мне получить например сегодня 100м бега, 500м на велосипеде?
Получаю данные так:

```
    PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> distanceResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(googleApiClient, DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA);
    distanceResult.setResultCallback(dailyTotalResult -> {
        if (dailyTotalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            for (DataPoint dataPoint : dailyTotalResult.getTotal().getDataPoints()) {
                distToday.setText(String.valueOf(dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).asFloat()));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: А дальше то что?

Comment: В чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: Не знаю как, могу получить только дистанцию например 100м, а как мне получить например сегодня 100м бега, 500 на велосипеде?